# Insert newlines with sed?

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I have a bunch of text files in a directory, where the following word occurs:

`GSM89103AATF`

Actually, the number can change, so another example could be `GSM89089AATF`. I need to replace these occurrences with `GSM89089\nAATF`, that is, insert a new line. Can I do this with `sed`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can with GNU `sed`:

```
 $ sed -r 's/(GSM[0-9]{5})(AATF)/\1\n\2/' file.in >file.out
```

The pattern matches the first part and then the second part in two separate capture groups. I have assumed that the first part always will be `GSM` followed by five digits.  The replacement simply pastes in the captured data from the two groups with a newline in-between.

The `-r` is needed because I've used an extended regular expression. Some implementations of `sed` use `-E` instead of `-r` for these kind of regular expressions.

On systems without GNU `sed`:

```
$ sed 's/\(GSM[0-9]\{5\}\)\(AATF\)/\1\
> \2' file.in >file.out
```

That is, use BRE instead of ERE (and drop the `-r` GNU extension) just add a `\` and press return after `\1`, and continue the replacement pattern on the next line.  `>` is a prompt, not something you type.

Comment: Thank you! You have saved my life. I made a mistake in some simulations output, and thanks to this I don't have to run the whole thing again :)

Comment: I am getting an error, does not recognize option `-r`. I am on Mac, seems it is not supported here. Any workaround?

Comment: @becko Ah, use `-E` instead, it does the same thing.

Comment: The interactive thing gives an error.... it does not recognize the whole thing as a single command. Note that I am running this inside a `for`, something like `for f in *; do sed -E 's/(GSM[0-9]+)(AATF)/\1\
\2' $f > $f.fix; done`, where there is a continued > between 1\ and \2

Comment: Nevermind, I installed `gsed` with brew to avoid all this nonsense. With `gsed` your first command works like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: for EREs, GNU `sed` came up with `-r` while BSDs came up with `-E` approximately at the same time, some BSDs have (recently) added support for `-r` as an alias for `-E` for compatibility with GNU `sed`, while GNU `sed` has added `-E` for compatibility with BSD (now documented as `-E` is going to make it to POSIX).

Answer (score 0):

This works on my mac and various linux distributions:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

PATTERN="(GSM[0-9]{5})(AATF)"

sed -E -e $"s_${PATTERN}_\1\\
\2_g" < file_with_values
```

Where:

- `PATTERN`: you can define the patter in a variable, making substitution expression easier to read
- `sed -E -e`: set `sed` to use extended regex (-E) and to use the provided script (-e)
- `$"..."`: is used to translate strings, and allows variables. Have a look here: [bash quoting](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting). It might not be safe in every situation, but in your case it should be fine
- `s_ ..._...\2_g`: is the substitution string; I'm using `_` as delimiters, so that you don't need to escape `/` and given that you need capture groups (`\1` and `\2`), it just makes the string easier to read. Please do note the `\\` followed by the new line. `$"..."` allows the use of new lines

If you don't need variables, you can use `$'....'` that is the dollar sign with single quotes. In that case, you can use `\n` but you can not insert a new line

The use of `$"..."` seem to be quite portable: my code, with a similar implementation, runs on docker alpine, centos, debian, fedora, ubuntu.